# Timeout exception with wp7 REST service call using WebClient

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, rest

Edit: I would love to give away the bounty on this question - time is almost up - all comments below are up to date but still no resolution.

Getting a strange error.  I have reduced my code to the absolute simplest form and still getting error for the following code.

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    private readonly WebClient webClient;

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += clientOpenRead_Completed;
    }

    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"validURL"));
    }

    private void clientOpenRead_Completed(object sender, System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result)) {
            Result.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }  
}
```

sr.ReadToEnd(); always returns empty string and when I inspect 'e.Result' from clientOpenRead_Completed it contains the following exception:

```
base    {"Timeouts are not supported on this stream."}  System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Other important validations:  The validURL works when requested from browser.  Also, the above code works fine when called in a Console app, also same URL and similar code works fine in Monodroid.

Finally, the service source non-WCF.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: stacktrace at the point I am inspecting e.Result: (from a slightly different project but with the same problem)

```
>   AppTest.dll!AppTest.Data.AsyncServiceProvider.clientOpenRead_Completed(object sender, System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) Line 20  C#
System.Net.dll!System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) + 0x15 bytes   
System.Net.dll!System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(object arg) + 0xc bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, bool isBinderDefault, System.Reflection.Assembly caller, bool verifyAccess, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)   
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) + 0x168 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters) + 0xa bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(object[] args) + 0x98 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x8 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(object[] args) + 0x2 bytes   
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() + 0xc bytes    
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority) + 0x83 bytes  
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context) + 0x8 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args) + 0x19 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(object[] args) + 0x2 bytes 
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam[] pParams, ref System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam pResult) + 0x5e bytes 
[External Code]
```

Comment: What's the stack trace on the exception?

Comment: That is one of the strange behaviors.  The app does not crash but when click on the button, nothing is displayed.  When I step through the code the e.Result is empty and when I inspect 'e.Result' from clientOpenRead_Completed it contains the above exception in 'e.Result.ReadTimeout'.  I appears the exception is being handled internally but i still need to deal with it so the app behaves appropriately.

Comment: What type of data are you downloading? radio stream? xml?

Comment: JSON response from the web service (text from response).  I can enter the same url into the browser and view a valid json response - the url and services are working.

Comment: BTW, e.Result.ReadTimeout always has that exception when you use OpenReadAsync so you should forget about that and look for other problems. Edit: if e.Result is empty, I would focus on validUrl, you're probably making a simple mistake.

Comment: @mostruash The URL is good. Exact code and URL work as console and monodroid build.

Comment: Do you try it on the emu or the actual device?

Comment: @mostruash Emu on wp7 so far can try on device - monodroid works on both emu and device.

Comment: It is not a problem with your code, it's not the URL thus it might be a problem with the WP emulator? It's a low probability but better be safe than be sorry.

Comment: @mostruash tried it on a wp7 device and got the same result.

Comment: Did you configure fiddler to compare your WP7 app vs browser requests to that URL? This may reveal minute differences in the headers. Note configuring fiddler to debug WP7 emulator is not trivial but there are blogs about this and it is worthwhile to do.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(yourUrl);

instead of

webClient.OpenReadAsync(yourUrl);

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same problem as stated above, and I was using OpenReadAsync method, now using DownloadStringAsync method works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [AllowReadStreamBuffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.allowreadstreambuffering%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) of `webClient` to `false` before calling `OpenReadAsync()`.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, I think you may have wrong (non windows phone) version of `System.Net.dll` referenced and this may be reason of problem in question. On 7.1 (standard install) it should be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Net.dll
```

In case you are on 7.0, it should be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\System.Net.dll
```

Comment: I initially thought to do that but that property does not seem to be available to me.  System.Net is include because WebClient is resolved:  Error 1 'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'AllowReadStreamBuffering' and no extension method 'AllowReadStreamBuffering' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: When I inspect webClient during execution, it does show the AllowReadStreamBuffering property (with value of true) but it cannot resolve it in code.

Comment: @IUnknown - this property of WebClient only exists in Silverlight. See my update.

Comment: This is the what i have in the project (should be the right one): C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Net.dll

Comment: @IUnknown - Wired. Hard to guess why it haven't this property then.

Comment: @IUnknown - In Properties window do you have `2.0.5.0` version for `System.Net` reference?

Comment: I found the problem, there were several other project types in the solution - even though the WP7 was set as startup I had to actually unload the other projects and then the AllowReadStreamBuffering was available. I am glad I was able to resolve that side problem but it still did not fix the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do the same with `HttpWebRequest` with different `ContentType` and `Accept` headers?

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(@"validURL");
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse((asyncresult) =>
{
    try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncresult);
        using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string response = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exception(ex);
    }
}, httpWebRequest);
```

Comment: I have not tried that yet but when I inspect the webClient object the request, response headers, and method are all set correctly.  Is there something specific you are trying to test with the above code?  Thanks

Comment: Once I have a problem: request returned an error, but all seems to be ok. Solution was to directly specify that Url is Absolute. From valid `http://` string it doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score -1):

Is the url hosted as https ? If so can you try hitting the URL from browser in the WP7 ?

What is the amount of data coming for this request ?

Comment: The size of the one I was testing was 63K but I also testing it on one that was just under 1K - same problem.  Good idea to test in the WP7 browser but unfortunately when I tried that it complained about the .json extension.  We use that for all json requests and I can't change that.